# Will Ubuntu be ok after formatting windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I currently have two partitions on one hard drive. Windows 7 is installed on partition C, and Ubuntu is installed on partition D.

I wish to format the Windows Partition and replace windows 7 with windows 8.1.
Ubuntu wasn't installed with Wubi.

Will Ubuntu be ok ?

Comment: No I cannot open Ubuntu files in Windows without special software "Ext2 Volume Manager". I installed Ubuntu from a flash drive I made from the ISO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows would rewrite MBR and purge grub from this drive sector, but don't worry - you can upgrade your Windows almost safe. Be sure you can run Ubuntu in recovery mode.

Here you have a guide how to do that: [Recovering Ubuntu After Installing Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows)

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure about that your Ubuntu driver will be protected its own format like **"ext4"**, you can uninstall or delete Win7. But you may face an error about bios autoloader. I mean you can't see your Ubuntu while pc is starting but you can edit settings in Windows typing in **cmd** , **msconfig** code. You can edit your startup time to e.g. 15 seconds and select Ubuntu when you want to be crazy in Ubuntu :-)

**Sum : I am sure you will have no problem uninstalling Win7 from your computer.**

Comment: You can't use Windows' bootloader to do that. See Roomy's answer. Windows' bootloader only supports Windows. Ubuntu's bootloader (GRUB) supports Ubuntu and Windows. Windows will overwrite the MBR with its own bootloader and therefore you can't choose for Ubuntu anymore. This can be easily fixed by simply booting from a Ubuntu Live CD and running `grub-install` to reinstall GRUB to the MBR. Note that this all isn't the case using EFI instead of MBR, but Windows 7 doesn't support this.